# boot repair doesn't find windows

Tags: grub

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 and Windows 7. Today I was getting an error message when booting into Win: "BootMgr missing." I ran the common system repair tasks available on the Windows installation media. This seemed to have fixed it. But then Mint was gone from grub menu. So I booted from a live media of that and installed and ran boot-repair. It says everything went fine — and, from what I can tell from this log, it found Windows — but in the grub menu I only get Mint.

Any suggestions?

http://paste2.org/D7ZLb8A1

When running "update-grub", I get

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-67-generic
  No volume groups found
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After managing to boot into windows via the USB installer containing WIndows, I ran bcdedit and noticed that it was using the USB's Bootmgr file to boot the local installation of Windows. I copied it to C:\, ran update-grub and now it's working.

No idea how bootmgr disappeared in the first place